# Why SFINAE has different behavior with gcc <11 vs >12?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, sfinae

I saw this example of using SFINAE to check if a type is streamable [here](https://github.com/mnafees/cpp_utils/tree/master/is_printable). However, I noticed that it is not portable, i.e. returns different results for templated types with different compilers. I'd be glad for any tips to understand the problem here.

The code below returns `true, false` with any version of clang++ and GCC 12 or higher, but `true, true` with earlier versions of GCC.

**You can try it online [here](https://godbolt.org/z/vqEYE8na5).**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename dummy = void>
struct is_printable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_printable<
    T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<
           std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::cout << std::declval<T>())>,
           std::ostream>>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_printable_v = is_printable<T>::value;

struct C {};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const C& c) {
    os << "C";
    return os;
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& v) {
    for (const auto& el : v) {
        os << el;
    }
    return os;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << is_printable_v<C> << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_printable_v<std::vector<int>> << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it may help, but if the `std::ostream& operator<<`  is before the `struct is_printable` both version are "true true"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& v)` won't be found by ADL (for `std::vector<int>`, it would for `std::vector<C>`) (and so need to be declared before usage to be usable).

That is why correct answer is `true`, `false`.
previous version of gcc misbehave on this.

Note: It is discouraged to overload operator for types which you don't own. std might in the future add that overload, and you will have ODR (One definition rule) violation. Same if another library does the same wrong thing than you.

Comment: Thank you @Jarod42. I realized that adding the overload to `std` namespace also works, i.e. all compilers agree that `vector` is printable. However, I see your concern about ODR so I was wondering if adding the overload to the `std` namespace cause any other problems? If the only concern about ODR is a future overload, then it is ok for me.

Comment: Adding most stuff in `std` is pedantically forbidden. only some specialization are ok. cleaner solution is to have a wrapper around vector, so you can have `operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PrettyPrinter<std::vector<T>>& v)`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a forwarding declaration help:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& v);
```

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& v);


template <typename T, typename dummy = void>
struct is_printable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_printable<
    T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<
           std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::cout << std::declval<T>())>,
           std::ostream>>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_printable_v = is_printable<T>::value;

struct C {};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const C& c) {
    os << "C";
    return os;
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& v) {
    for (const auto& el : v) {
        os << el;
    }
    return os;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << is_printable_v<C> << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_printable_v<std::vector<int>> << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Demo : https://godbolt.org/z/qKz537TPr

I know I didn't answer "why both version behave differently" but I think it may help :)